# UWP: UnauthorisedAccessException to LocalState folder

Tags: c#, uwp, storagefile, storagefolder

UnauthorisedAccessException in c# UWP Application
I am suddenly getting this error when trying to access files in LocalState.  Haven't made any changes to code. Worked fine until this morning.

```
//in public class
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;  
Windows.Storage.StorageFile pHSensorsFile;
public string[] pHSensorsArray;
//async void ReadSensors()
Task t = Task.Run(async () => { return pHSensorsFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync("pHSensors.txt"); });
t.Wait();
//This throws the error:    
 pHSensorsArray = await File.ReadAllLinesAsync(pHSensorsFile.Path);
```

Error details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Packages\27924aef-1d51-48c2-9893-dace8724640c_snwgte540zp2r\LocalState\pHSensors.txt' is denied.'

I have tried re-opening the Solution, restarting VS2019. Has this happened to anyone else?

Comment: Maybe you could get another file of the LocalState folder with your code to check whether the exception is related to the file pHSensors.txt.

Comment: Already tried that, same code for a different sensor, same error. Its weird I haven't touched this section of code for about a week..

Comment: OK I restarted the PC and this problem went away.  Shutting the Solution and restarting VS did not work.